# How to Display post from specific tag on top of category page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags

I want to create a div, like an editor choice zone, that display the post tagged "editor-choice" on the top of each category page. Of course it will only display post from current category page. Thanks

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what you just said. If you try to explain it in more detail I'm sure you'll get your answer.

Comment: Sorry, i m gone try to explain...
In pages of each categories I want to display the post tagged "editor-choice", but not all the post tagged "editor-choice" only the post post of the current category

Answer (score 0):

If some one is interested, here is the code:

```
<?php 
    if (is_category( )) {
    // this grabs the current category slug
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
 }

 // this is the query to sort the tag only with the CURRENT CATEGORY by slug

 $args = 'tag=editor-choice&category_name='.$yourcat->slug.'&category_title='.single_cat_title( '', false );

 query_posts( $args );

 // The Loop
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   echo '<li>';
   the_title();
   echo '</li>';
 endwhile;

 wp_reset_query();

?>
```